# sql query (Show unique rows in column)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have following type of data in my Sql server:-

```
Field         Value   Month

Administrative  5   November
Counteracting   7   November
District1       9   November
District2       6   November
Administrative  1   December
Counteracting   2   December
District1       3   December
District2       4   December
Administrative  9   January
Counteracting   8   January
District1       5   January
District2       6   January
```

Now the problem is I am not able to figure out that how to show this data in the following format:-

```
Field         November   December   January

Administrative  5          1          9
Counteracting   7          2          8  
District1       9          3          5
District2       6          4          6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to do is [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) the data. There are a few ways to perform this.  If you know the values ahead of time, then you can hard-code the values.

You can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` statement:

```
select field,
  sum(case when month ='November' then value end) November,
  sum(case when month ='December' then value end) December,
  sum(case when month ='January' then value end) January,
  etc
from yourtable
group by field
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bfa25/1)

In SQL Server 2005+ you can use the `PIVOT` function:

```
select field, November, December, January
from
(
  select field,
    value, month
  from yourtable
) src
pivot
(
  sum(value)
  for month in (November, December, January, etc)
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bfa25/3)

If you had an unknown number of values to transform into columns then you could use dynamic sql to pivot the data.

Comment: I have a feeling that the OP may have 9 other months.

Comment: @njk, so? That will add about 2 minutes to the developement time.

Comment: @HLGEM Right, the 2 minutes that was used to add the `PIVOT` to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

That is a typical pivoting problem. Check out the SQL Server PIVOT statement: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Pivot, check out example:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample.aspx